# Is the word "bespoke" associated with Southern American English, kind of how "bonafied" is in my mind?

Tags: adjectives, dialects

Is *bespoke* associated with the American South, as "bonafied" (*bona fide*, properly) is to me?  When I hear the latter, it brings to mind aristocratic Southern gentlemen sipping mint juleps; when I hear the former, it brings to mind some Negro sharecropper telling his son, "we're gonna get you your first bespoke suit..."  I can't recall where these images come from, exactly....

Comment: I've lived in California - Northern and Southern - all my life, and I've only met a few people who pronounce "bona fide", or "bona fides", correctly.  "Bonnafied" is definitely not just a Southernism.
Even (most of) the lawyers I know pronounce it as "bonnafied."  Ick!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Bespoke*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1226106#m_en_us1226106) is definitely a Briticism, though I wouldn't be surprised if it is popular in the South. I would think that Americans would sooner use [*tailor-made*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1296811?rskey=bZ0eDe&result=1#m_en_us1296811), however.

Comment: I think we Brits are deserting *bespoke* in favour of *tailor-made* too. Certainly I never heard of *bespoke* cigarettes as distinct from hand-rolled ones. But the poor students of today, talking longingly of what they can't afford, will be the rulers of both society and language tomorrow.

Comment: *Tailor-made* is certainly the standard term in most of the U.S. I don't know about the South, however.

Comment: Some British web-builders speak of "bespoke" websites, meaning requiring more than an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: I'm a Southerner, and I've never heard "bespoke" except as the past-tense of "bespeak," and even that's uncommon. Yay for learning a new word!

Answer (score -1):

Bespoke is indeed a popular British term for anything custom made.  The word is (IMHO) over-used by academics and consultants there to refer to anything from a piece of engineering to a business process.  In translating documents to American, I typically replace Bespoke with Custom.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue OP is interested in: in *American* English, is the word more associated with a Southern dialect?